# Map Creation Error Java

Tags: java

When I am trying to create a map in java, I type the following code:

```
    Map <String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

I get an error saying Map and Hashmap cannot be resolved to a type, any help?

Comment: May be a stupid question, but are the appropriate packages imported?

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, CTRL-SHIFT-O to organize and import the appropriate packages.

Answer (score 7):

Add

```
import java.util.Map; 
import java.util.HashMap;
```

to the top of your Java file.  Just after your package declaration, but before anything else.

Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html, which explains all about importing packages.

Depending on which IDE you're using, there'll be hot-keys to insert these for you, without you having to type them.  Check your IDE's documentation for this.